# HTML button layout positioning

Tags: html, button, layout

I am attempting to create web portal page using standard HTML, or HTML 5. I understand the concepts of HTML, however coming from a software background I do have a little difficulty with the more intricate parts of layouts and such.

The basic premise for the layout in mind is quite simple: A centered image, with a number of surrounding buttons. Im having a tough time with the layout of the buttons.

A visual representation of the layout:

http://imgur.com/edit

Currently, the center image is displaying but I have difficulty positioning the button elements.

Im a little confused as to how to layout the webpage. Should I have a centered `<div>` tag with `<buttons elements surrounding this>`, or the centered  with a bunch of other centered `<div>`s.

Also, if there is a more refined approach to this problem using HTML5, I would be very interested to learn about it.

Many thanks,
J

HTML Code

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"></head>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>Web Portal</h1>

    <div class="globe" align="center">
        <img src="center_img.png" alt="logo" height="420" width="420">
    </div>
    <div class="button" align="center">
        <button type="Button">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the link betwen your sample code and your visual representation. What do you want exacly?

Comment: Id like to have a layout mirroring the visual representation, the code supplied was just an example of my approach so far.

Answer (score 0):

Even i didn't get what exactly you want. but for an image sourrounded by buttons try this code

```
<body>

<h1>Web Portal</h1>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
        <td align="center" ><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
        <td><img src="center_img.png" alt="logo" height="420" width="420"></td>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
        <td align="center" ><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
        <td><button type="Button">Click me!</button></td>
    </tr>         
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Jithin, its not what I am looking for though. I have included an example in the image of the original post :)

Comment: The layout you've shown in the image also can be achieved using table layout using <tr>s and <td>s . You can also add furthur tables inside <td>s.